# Python open file in specific application using xdg-utils?

Tags: python, xdgutils

i have this line of code in my python script:

```
            os.system("xdg-open " + "User_interaction.py")
```

It works fine and opens the python file in the default application associated with the .py file type but i want it to run the file.  I know i could usually just import the module but the user_interaction file is already importing the file that is code is written in so they cannot import each other.

How do i get the python script to execute the user_interaction script?

Cheers.

Comment: Generally, if you've got circular dependencies in your modules, you're doing something wrong and should consider refactoring to break the circle.

Comment: xdg-utils is not linux specific: it runs on any xdg-compliant system

Comment: I agree, but sadly the hand in for my project is a couple of days away and so i dont have time to rework it.  This was my first python project and so i would want to rewrite most it. So badly written but oh well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this `os.system('python file.py')` in your file

test.py

```
import os
os.system('python hello.py')
```

hello.py

```
print "hello world"
```

run `python test.py`, it will print out "hello world"